# SwiftUI Why does context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue return only initial value?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement some UIKit components in my SwiftUI app. I have successfully added UISlider to my SwiftUI view. But one thing is bugging me. When I move slider, value is updated ok, but I am curios why context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue stays the same? Here is my implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UISliderView: UIViewRepresentable {
typealias UIViewType = UISlider

@Binding var value: Double
var minValue: Double
var maxValue: Double

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
    let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
    slider.maximumValue = Float(minValue)
    slider.maximumValue = Float(maxValue)
    slider.value = Float(value)
    slider.addTarget(context.coordinator,
                     action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
                     for: .valueChanged)
    return slider
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {
    print("Value: \(value)")
    print("Wrapped value: \(context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue)")
    uiView.value = Float(value)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    let coordinator = Coordinator(value: $value)
    coordinator.id = 5
    return coordinator
}

class Coordinator: NSObject {
    var value: Binding<Double>
    var id: Int = 0
    
    init(value: Binding<Double>) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        value.wrappedValue = Double(sender.value)
    }
}
}
```

Now this is part that trouble me:

```
print("Value: \(value)")
print("Wrapped value: \(context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue)")
```

These values should be the same, or at least I expect them to be the same, but yet they are not?

Comment: It is just a question of update order... don't check it there. Just use - it works correctly. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: If this was the case of update order then context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue would have previous value... In this case if you call UISlider init with 30 for value, context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue will always print 30. Also moving slider should first be called on Coordinator binding.

Comment: As Asperi says, it's a timing issue. The `context.coordinator` haven't been updated yet. If you make the `coordinator` an instance variable, and compare it, you'll see that it _is_ updated. It's just that the Context, which is a struct, haven't been updated yet. You shouldn't care about it.

Comment: Also the code in `updateUIView` is irrelevant in your example, as the view _already_ have the correct value. The `updateUIView` code is used for when you change the binding from outside, i.e. if you had a button that would change the binding from a ContentView or the likes.

Answer (score 1):

**The credit should go to @Asperi and @Claus Jørgensen**

If you print the wrapped value of the context.coordinator, asynchronously, as shown below, its value is correct.

I have no idea why this happens, and I'm too curious about it. In theory, as the context.coordinator.value should be the same binding of the UISliderView and the Coordinator. Hence they should update exactly the same time.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        UISliderView(value: $value, minValue: 0, maxValue: 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct UISliderView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UISlider

    @Binding var value: Double
    var minValue: Double
    var maxValue: Double

    init(value: Binding<Double>, minValue: Double, maxValue: Double) {
        print("UISliderView", #function)

        self._value = value
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        print("UISliderView", #function)

        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        slider.maximumValue = Float(minValue)
        slider.maximumValue = Float(maxValue)
//        slider.value = Float(value)
        slider.addTarget(context.coordinator,
                         action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
                         for: .valueChanged)
        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {
        print("UISliderView", #function, "coordinator", ObjectIdentifier(context.coordinator))

        print("UISliderView", "Value: \(value)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("UISliderView", "Wrapped value: \(context.coordinator.value.wrappedValue)")
        }
        uiView.value = Float(value)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        print("UISliderView", #function)

        let coordinator = Coordinator(value: $value)
        coordinator.id = 5
        return coordinator
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var value: Binding<Double>
        var id: Int = 0

        init(value: Binding<Double>) {
            self.value = value
            super.init()
            print("Coordinator", #function, ObjectIdentifier(self))
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
            print("Coordinator", #function, "newValue:", value.wrappedValue)
            value.wrappedValue = Double(sender.value)
        }
    }
}
```

```
UISliderView init(value:minValue:maxValue:)
UISliderView makeCoordinator()
Coordinator init(value:) ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView makeUIView(context:)
UISliderView updateUIView(_:context:) coordinator ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView Value: 0.0
UISliderView Wrapped value: 0.0
UISliderView updateUIView(_:context:) coordinator ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView Value: 0.0
UISliderView Wrapped value: 0.0
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.0
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.0
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.0
UISliderView updateUIView(_:context:) coordinator ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView Value: 0.03875968977808952
UISliderView Wrapped value: 0.03875968977808952
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.03875968977808952
UISliderView updateUIView(_:context:) coordinator ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView Value: 0.1550387591123581
UISliderView Wrapped value: 0.1550387591123581
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.1550387591123581
UISliderView updateUIView(_:context:) coordinator ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000018b4d50)
UISliderView Value: 0.23255814611911774
UISliderView Wrapped value: 0.23255814611911774
Coordinator valueChanged(_:) newValue: 0.23255814611911774
```